# functor as a base class in C++

Tags: c++, functor

I have a functor base class and a functor derived class that looks like this:

```
class ReadSensor
{
public:
    ReadSensor();
    virtual ~ReadSensor(void){}
    virtual int operator()(void) = 0;
};

class ReadSensorDummy : public ReadSensor
{
public:
    ReadSensorDummy() : x(0) {}
    ReadSensorDummy(int x): x(x) {}
    ~ReadSensorDummy(void) {}
    int operator() (void) { return x;}
private:
    int x;
};
```

I am creating it as so:

```
ReadSensor *rs =  new ReadSensorDummy(5);
```

It compiles, but I get the following link error:

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl ReadSensor::ReadSensor(void)" (??0ReadSensor@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ReadSensorDummy::ReadSensorDummy(int)" (??0ReadSensorDummy@@QEAA@H@Z) W:\SafetySystemTest.obj
```

What is wrong? A dynamic_cast shouldn't be needed, but I did try it and it didn't help.

Comment: If all your class does is provide a ()->int functor, why not use std::function?  typedef std::function<int()> ReadSensor;  ReadSensor MakeReadSensorDummy(int x) { return [x]() { return x; } }, or ReadSensor MakeComplexSensor() { ComplexState x; return [x]() { return x.calculate(); } }...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared the intention to define a constructor for `ReadSensor`, but the compiler did not find one defined in any of your source files. You can try defining an empty one, or removing the declaration.

Comment: I tried adding an empty constructor, but still got the same link error. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Jim : Are you positive? [This](http://ideone.com/u8fDTv) works fine, as does [this](http://ideone.com/zhfI1n), so there must be something you're not showing us.

Comment: @Jim, then you didn't ry it right.  Changing to `ReadSensor() {}` for the constructor compiles for me.